# UWP xaml: Changing panel creates button disappear

Tags: user-interface, button, uwp

I'm creating a UWP project. I have a main usercontrol and some sub-Usercontrols that i what to display depending on the user selection.
On top of the main usercontrol, i have some buttons with an image that the user can select to go from one panel to another :

[image]
On each sub-panel i also have buttons (one for comming back to main panel, etc...).

[image]

The whole panel display is managed by a IntToVisibilityConverter that translate the panel index into visibility and back and forth.

If i open the app with let say PanelIndex = 0, buttons on Panel 0 display correctly, but when I change PanelIndex to 1 -> button on panel 1 do not appear.

Now then, if I open it with PanelIndex = 1, buttons on panel 1 display correctly now, and then by coming back to panel 0 -> panel 0 button disappear.

does any one know why buttons can appear or disappear?
is it a normal behaviour? (and i'm missing something)
is there a way to fix it or at least force an invalidatevisual on the new displayed panel?

EDIT:

The button is like so

```
<Button x:Class="MyApp.UIElements.AnimatedButton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:MyApp.UIElements"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        xmlns:utils="using:MyApp.Utils"
        Name="Control">
    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <utils:LayoutTransformer x:Name="transformer">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="/Resources/MyGif.gif"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            </Grid>
        </utils:LayoutTransformer>
        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Control,Path=Image}"
               IsHitTestVisible="False"
               Margin="30" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

the panel changing is done in the viewmodel using an int that sets the visibility of each panel accordingly. Nothing special about that.

I'll add that when the app is running, if a CTRL + X and re CTRL + V any button, it then shows up (hence the invalidatevisual hint).

Thank world

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet about how you did it?

Comment: May be since you are using int to visibility converter and you binded the visibility directly to button so when it return collapse your whole button gone off because of visibility collapse. you can test it by turning off the converter